# Export to Excel as a background task in MVC 5

Tags: c#, background, task-parallel-library, export-to-excel

I'm developing an MVC 5 application which has requirement to export huge data to excel,
So i am running this in a separate thread and works as expected. But when the user navigates to other page export is being cancelled. How can i achieve this.
Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your background task being cancelled when the user navigates away, or do you just mean that the user does not get the result because they left the page before the result was ready?

Comment: HI Eric, thanks for the response. I mean to say user does not get the result as he left the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> user does not get the result as he left the page

A typical strategy for allowing users to retrieve the result of a long-running process is to associate some sort of token with their processing request (it can be a GUID, a database ID, etc.) Associate the result of the process with that ID.

A simple scheme would be to save each file in the file system using a GUID as part of the file name. You would also want to have a database table associating the user with 0:N GUIDs of long-running processes they have started, and probably a status column indicating whether the job is complete. You could also save the generated file into a database. However you save the result of the process, be sure and provide for some sort of mechanism to periodically clean up old data.

Provide users with a page where they can check on the status of their long-running processes, and download the result if the process is complete. Depending on your situation, you might also email users a link they can use to download the file once completed.

Note that using TPL to process the request might not be the best plan. For a full list of alternatives, check out

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx